# File "obj\Debug\android\AndroidManifest.xml" cannot be opened

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I get this error when running Code Analysis:

```
Error Input file "obj\Debug\android\AndroidManifest.xml" cannot be opened. 
Could not find file 'C:\Development\Acquaintance\Acquaint.Native\Acquaint.Native.Droid\obj\Debug\android\AndroidManifest.xml'.  
Acquaint.Native.Droid
```

It looks like [this was noted as this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36183) and it claims a fix was entered (Comment 13) in January 2016, yet I still get this error.

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Version 14.0.25.25123 Update 2.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you try to create a new project, this time without the dot in the project name? Then add your code and run to check if it can be build.

Comment: The dot is introduced by Xamarin, I think. The project name is Acquaint and then it adds the .Native and .Droid